# Running application on remote server using Python SSH

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

Is there a possibility to execute an application residing in a remote windows machine like this? The remote host is running a Cygwin SSH server and I am running the below python script from my laptop. The application "xt-ocd.exe" is in the specified path "c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3"

```
ssh.connect('135.24.200.100',username = 'cyg_server',password = 'force')
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd '/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3';./xt-ocd.exe")
```

The above script fails to work. I am not sure whether I am on the right track. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the conmer of spaces in your path is correct? `Program Files     (x86)` seems weird to me as it contains 5 spaces in your example (don't know why the comment here doesn't display it right, though)

Answer (score 1):

The line `"cd '/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3';./xt-ocd.exe"` does not actually represent one single command, but 2 different ones (`cd` and `xt-ocd`). That has to be interpreted by a shell.

If the working directory does not matter you could try to use the full path of the executable as proposed by Iskren. But if you really need to set the working directory, you could try :

`stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("bash -c \"cd '/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3';./xt-ocd.exe\"")`

Comment: Serge, I got this output: stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("bash -c \"cd '/cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3';./xt-ocd.exe\"")
stderr.readlines()
[u'bash: line 0: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3: No such file or directory\n',
 u'bash: ./xt-ocd.exe: No such file or directory\n']

Comment: Serge, its not changing the directory: stdout.readlines()
[u'/var/empty\n']

Comment: Error message: stderr.readlines()
[u'bash: line 0: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program Files     (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3: No such file or directory\n']

Comment: @user3565150 Just to be sure, what gives : `ssh.exec_command("bash -c \"echo foo; pwd; echo bar\"")` ?

Comment: I got this: stdout.readlines()
[u'foo\n', u'/var/empty\n', u'bar\n']

Comment: @user3565150 It means that is correctly interprets my multi-line command. Could you twice control the path for the cd (is the number of spaces correct, could a tab be there, etc.) ? Ideally, you should open a ssh terminal, cd into the directory, pwd and copy and paste that ...

Comment: Serge, in my comment to Iskren above, you can see the error message is coming as a syntax error in bash while I did not use bash there....but there seems to be a bash syntax error in the ssh command given. stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3/xt-ocd.exe')

Comment: @user3565150 Maybe the `bash -c` is implied. But I now think `glglgl` guess is good : doudle control the spaces in command path.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is with the `cd` you use, it's not a command but a shell function and you don't have a shell. Try executing like this:

```
ssh.exec_command('/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3/xt-ocd.exe')
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, this was the output: (<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2ca2e90L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>,
 <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (EOF received) (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2ca2e90L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>,
 <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2ca2e90L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>>>)

Comment: I tried this now: stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3/xt-ocd.exe')

Comment: And the output was: stderr.readlines()
[u"bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('\n",
 u"bash: -c: line 0: `/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Tensilica/Xtensa OCD Daemon 9.0.3/xt-ocd.exe'\n"]

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the full path to launch the program instead of change working directory and then start it.